# Как сделать чтобы выбрался элемент выпадающего списка, если поставить флаг у соответствующего элемента в другом списке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два списка, выпадающий и список элементов с чекбоксами.
Нужно, чтобы при выборе элементов из второго, выбирались соответствующие элементы и в первом. 
Причем, если после загрузки страницы в первом уже были выбраны элементы, то и во втором они тоже должны быть с флажками.

Знаю что основное, что нужно - это `.change(function()` но за час ничего путного не родилось в голове.

Как связать пока не представляю..

```js
$('.form-type-checkbox').change(function() {


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" name="field_akctest_tid[]" id="edit-field-akctest-tid" size="3" class="form-select valid">
  <option value="821">Акции</option>
  <option value="822">Мероприятия</option>
  <option value="823">Розыгрыши</option>
</select>


<div class="form-type-checkbox">
  <label class="option">
    <input type="checkbox" value="821" class="form-checkbox">Акция</label>
  <label class="option">
    <input type="checkbox" value="822" class="form-checkbox">Мероприятие</label>
  <label class="option ">
    <input type="checkbox" value="823" сlass="form-checkbox">Розыгрыш</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну подумайте не час, а два-три-четыре. Зачем сразу на ruSO бежать?

Comment: не сразу. Знаю способ но не универсальный. Наверное как то можно связать, value обоих списков, но тут у меня вообще пусто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Обновлено**

Тут и думать не надо, достаточно в поиске покопаться по ключу "jquery выбор select":

```js
$(function() {

  $('.form-type-checkbox input:checked').each(function(index, el) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#edit-field-akctest-tid option[value=" + val + "]").attr('selected', true);
  });

  $('.form-type-checkbox input').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
      $("#edit-field-akctest-tid option[value=" + val + "]").prop('selected', true);
    } else {
      $("#edit-field-akctest-tid option[value=" + val + "]").prop('selected', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" name="field_akctest_tid[]" id="edit-field-akctest-tid" size="3" class="form-select valid">
  <option value="821">Акции</option>
  <option value="822">Мероприятия</option>
  <option value="823">Розыгрыши</option>
</select>


<div class="form-type-checkbox">
  <label class="option">
    <input type="checkbox" value="821" class="form-checkbox">Акция</label>
  <label class="option">
    <input type="checkbox" value="822" class="form-checkbox">Мероприятие</label>
  <label class="option ">
    <input type="checkbox" value="823" сlass="form-checkbox" checked>Розыгрыш</label>
</div>
```

Comment: В первой части скрипта нужно было наоборот (второй список зависит от первого при загрузке) но тут я разобрался, благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.form-type-checkbox input').change(function() {
  var y = $(this);
  $("#edit-field-akctest-tid option").each(function(item, x) {
    if ($(x).attr("value") == y.val()) {
      $(x).prop("selected", $(y).prop("checked"));
    }
  })
});
$('#edit-field-akctest-tid').change(function() {
  var y = $("#edit-field-akctest-tid option:selected");
  $(".form-type-checkbox input").each(function(item, x) {
    if ($(x).attr("value") == y.attr("value")) {
      $(x).prop("checked", $(y).prop("selected"));
    }
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" name="field_akctest_tid[]" id="edit-field-akctest-tid" size="3" class="form-select valid">
  <option value="821">Акции</option>
  <option value="822">Мероприятия</option>
  <option value="823">Розыгрыши</option>
</select>


<div class="form-type-checkbox">
  <label class="option">
    <input type="checkbox" value="821" class="form-checkbox">Акция</label>
  <label class="option">
    <input type="checkbox" value="822" class="form-checkbox">Мероприятие</label>
  <label class="option ">
    <input type="checkbox" value="823" сlass="form-checkbox">Розыгрыш</label>
</div>
```

Comment: чет не пашет третий option

Comment: @Jean-Claude изменил...